# Unknown type name 'UIBackgroundFetchResult'

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am trying to configure UrbanAirship for one of my iOS apps. I've completed the configurations as explained on the tutorial page here:
http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html

But when I build the project I get the following error:
`Unknown type name 'UIBackgroundFetchResult'`

The error occurs four times in the file UAPush.h (downloaded from UrbanAirship site)
I also tried running the sample code provided in the zip file on UrbanAirship tutorial page, it has the same problem as well. Did anyone else face the same problem?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Urban Airship 3.0 requires the latest sdk, so you need to update your Xcode to 5.0.

If you can't, Urban Airship 2.1 still builds find with older Xcode versions.

Comment: Thanks .. it seems you were right. But when I updated xCode, it just changed the errors. Now the error is: `UAirship.h` file not found.

Comment: I've given correct header path as mentioned in the UA docs. But still it cannot locate the header files.

Comment: Validate the Airship directory path is relative to the xcode project file, is up to date, and is set on the target and scheme you are running.

Comment: I am still getting this error,i am using Urban Airship 3.0 on xcode 4.5. Is there any link available for lower versions of urban airship. I am getting "Unknown type name 'UIBackgroundFetchResult'" this error on xcode 5 as well. Please provide a solution for it ASAP.

Comment: I got the same error (in xCode 5, even with their demo app).  I just changed to use the Urban Airship iOS5-3.0.1 archive and it compiled fine.

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship provide latest sdk which is for ios7 or xcode 5.

If you want to download for xcode 4.* than u can go for below link:-

http://com.urbanairship.filereleases.s3.amazonaws.com/libUAirship-2.1.0.zip

I hope you will get it.